# spatial clustering in R (simple example)

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, hierarchical-clustering

I have this simple `data.frame`

```
 lat<-c(1,2,3,10,11,12,20,21,22,23)
 lon<-c(5,6,7,30,31,32,50,51,52,53)
 data=data.frame(lat,lon)
```

The idea is to find the spatial clusters based on the distance

First, I plot the map (lon,lat) :

```
plot(data$lon,data$lat)
```

[image]

so clearly I have three clusters based in the distance between the position of points.

For this aim, I've tried this code in R :

```
d= as.matrix(dist(cbind(data$lon,data$lat))) #Creat distance matrix
d=ifelse(d<5,d,0) #keep only distance < 5
d=as.dist(d)
hc<-hclust(d) # hierarchical clustering
plot(hc)
data$clust <- cutree(hc,k=3) # cut the dendrogram to generate 3 clusters
```

This gives :

[image]

Now I try to plot the same points but with colors from clusters

```
plot(data$x,data$y, col=c("red","blue","green")[data$clust],pch=19)
```

Here the results

[image]

Which is not what I'm looking for.

Actually, I want to find something like this plot

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: I've tried to follow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095643/approaches-for-spatial-geodesic-latitude-longitude-clustering-in-r-with-geodesic

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you are clustering the distances that way... If you use `hc <- hclust(dist(data)); clust <- cutree(hc, 3)` it works as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
lat<-c(1,2,3,10,11,12,20,21,22,23)
lon<-c(5,6,7,30,31,32,50,51,52,53)

km <- kmeans(cbind(lat, lon), centers = 3)
plot(lon, lat, col = km$cluster, pch = 20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a different approach. First it assumes that the coordinates are WGS-84 and not UTM (flat). Then it clusters all neighbors within a given radius to the same cluster using hierarchical clustering (with method = `single`, which adopts a 'friends of friends' clustering strategy).

In order to compute the distance matrix, I'm using the `rdist.earth` method from the package `fields`. The default earth radius for this package is 6378.388 (the equatorial radius) which might not be what one is looking for, so I've changed it to 6371. See [this article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/) for more info.

```
library(fields)
lon = c(31.621785, 31.641773, 31.617269, 31.583895, 31.603284)
lat = c(30.901118, 31.245008, 31.163886, 30.25058, 30.262378)
threshold.in.km <- 40
coors <- data.frame(lon,lat)

#distance matrix
dist.in.km.matrix <- rdist.earth(coors,miles = F,R=6371)

#clustering
fit <- hclust(as.dist(dist.in.km.matrix), method = "single")
clusters <- cutree(fit,h = threshold.in.km)

plot(lon, lat, col = clusters, pch = 20)
```

This could be a good solution if you don't know the number of clusters (like the k-means option), and is somewhat related to the dbscan option with minPts = 1.

---EDIT---

With the original data:

```
lat<-c(1,2,3,10,11,12,20,21,22,23)
lon<-c(5,6,7,30,31,32,50,51,52,53)
data=data.frame(lat,lon)

dist <- rdist.earth(data,miles = F,R=6371) #dist <- dist(data) if data is UTM
fit <- hclust(as.dist(dist), method = "single")
clusters <- cutree(fit,h = 1000) #h = 2 if data is UTM
plot(lon, lat, col = clusters, pch = 20)
```

Comment: I found your answer very very helpful, could you add the same for k-means method also?

Comment: @user3875610 The transition to k-means is not very intuitive, since one can't use a distance matrix as an input to k-means (it can't compute means with only distances). Additionally, in this use case you often don't know the number of clusters, and you prefer to use a density based approach like hclust or dbscan. Having said that, if you want to use k-medoids (similar to kmeans) check out this answer : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/perform-k-means-or-its-close-kin-clustering-with-only-a-distance-matrix-not-p

Answer (score 6):

As you have a spatial data to cluster, so [`DBSCAN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) is best suited for you data.
You can do this clustering using  `dbscan()` function provided by [**fpc**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/index.html), a **R** package.

```
library(fpc)

lat<-c(1,2,3,10,11,12,20,21,22,23)
lon<-c(5,6,7,30,31,32,50,51,52,53)

DBSCAN <- dbscan(cbind(lat, lon), eps = 1.5, MinPts = 3)
plot(lon, lat, col = DBSCAN$cluster, pch = 20)
```

[image: Plot of DBSCAN Clustering]

Comment: How do you get/guess `eps` parameter?