# spatial geodesic location clustering - ggplot2 error

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am using a code earlier posted by @jlhoward at [Approaches for spatial geodesic latitude longitude clustering in R with geodesic or great circle distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095643/approaches-for-spatial-geodesic-latitude-longitude-clustering-in-r-with-geodesic)

However, I am trying to implement the same thing for Sweden. When I load the shp file(s) I get an error from ggplots. How can I solve this? My code is below:

```
map.SE  <- readOGR(dsn="sweden-latest", layer="places")
map.df  <- fortify(map.SE)

ggplot(map.df)+
  geom_path(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat, color=factor(clust)), size=4)+
  scale_color_discrete("Cluster")+
  coord_fixed()
```

The error that I get is at the "fortify" step - `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class SpatialPointsDataFrame`

Comment: actually the data 'df' in the grom_point is another data set with the clusters and lat/longs. i used the exact code from the other post that i mentioned (link in the question). Anyway, the error that i get at the fortify step that is before ggplot

Comment: Is there any way you can provide the shapefiles?

Comment: yes - i download it from here - http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/SE.zip

Comment: I see two text files, but not shapefiles.

Comment: sorry, provided the wrong link. here is the correct file - http://www.filedropper.com/sweden-places-shape

Comment: One way to get sweden shapefiles would be like this. You use the `raster` package. `sweden <- getData("GADM", country = "Sweden", level = 1); map <- fortify(sweden); ggplot() + geom_map(data = map, map = map, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id, group = group)) + coord_map()` You can add `geom_point()` to this if you want.

Comment: thanks! however, the website it's pulling data from (http://data.biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/) is not responding / not connecting / timing out. Any other similar solution?

Comment: I see. It does not usually take that much time. You may want to try again. Otherwise, you can directly go to GADM and download shapefiles. http://www.gadm.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy ways to get GIS shapefiles is to use the `raster` package. You can download the GADM data. Then, you can do all sorts of ggplot business later. As you intended, you can add dots using `geom_point()`, for example.

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

sweden <- getData("GADM", country = "Sweden", level = 1)
map <- fortify(sweden)

ggplot() + 
geom_map(data = map, map = map, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id, group = group)) +
coord_map()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this looks the best out of all ways i tried including google maps based pictures. could you please also help me with plotting the data on this map. i have clustered database of lat-longs.

Comment: it works now. will share code once finalized. thanks!

Comment: @PreritAhuja Glas to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your shapefile is point data, not polygons as in the linked example (that uses the polygon as an outline).  `fortify()` is used in this context to convert polygons into a series of vertices for plotting in `ggplot2`, so will never work for point data.

If you want to replicate their results, you need a polygon shapefile for Sweden to use in place of the Californian one used in the example.

Comment: many thanks! let me find the polygon shapefile and confirm soon.